# How to increment for loop by 2 in Expect script?

Tags: bash, expect

I have this piece of code in bash script which is working perfectly fine and increment the variable by one. I want to be able to increment by two so that there are two registrations happening at once in parallel. Below is the piece of code for expect:

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF2'

set tarts [split $env(Tarts)]
set ips [split $env(IPs)]

puts "Tarts to be updated: $tarts"
puts "IPs of Tarts: $ips"

for { set index 0 } { $index < [llength $tarts] } { incr index } {
puts "In Loop: $index"
set tart [lindex $tarts $index]
puts "TARTS Num: $tart"
set ip [lindex $ips $index]
puts "IP: $ip"

puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
puts "Registering Stations on Tarts"
puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"

        spawn telnet $ip 6187
        set timeout -1
        expect {
                "*traffic*" {
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
                puts "Registering Group1, Group2 of Tart#: [lindex $tart $index]"
                send "traffic map rate reg_group1 30000\r"
                send "traffic map rate reg_group2 30000\r"
                puts "wait 300 seconds .."
                send "traffic go\r"
                sleep 300
              
                 sleep 2
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
                puts "Setting hold_time for 4kagents to 20000s"
                puts "traffic map param 4kagents hold_time=20000"
                send "traffic map param 4kagents hold_time=20000\r"
                puts "traffic map param 4kagents hold_time=20000"
                send "traffic map param 4kagents hold_time=20000\r"
                puts "wait 5 seconds .."
                sleep 5
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"

                sleep 2
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
                puts "Logging in Agents using map 4kagents on Tart#: [lindex $tart $index]"
                puts "traffic map param 4kagents 1"
                send "traffic map param 4kagents 1\r"
                puts "wait 120 seconds .."
                sleep 120
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
                puts "``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"

                }

                puts "wait 3 seconds"
                sleep 3

                send -- "^]"
                expect -exact "^\]\rtelnet> "
                send -- "close\r"
                expect eof
        }
}
EOF2
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

I have tried incrementing the variable by 1 like `set tarts [split $env(Tarts) + 1]` / `set ips [split $env(IPs) + 1]` but I am getting syntax errors.
Can someone guide please?

Comment: Why are you making it into a here-document instead of making it into a pure `expect` script?

Comment: This is being done to automate a test tool.

Comment: Sure, but can't you use the `#!/usr/bin/expect` shebang and skip the here-document in your `bash` script? It should also be useful to get syntax highlighting from your IDE etc.

Comment: Yes I am doing that at the top. This is just a block of code. It is working fine this so I have opted to go with it. Can you please guide how to increment the index by 2 if you have an idea of expect scripts syntax?

Comment: No, that's not what you are doing. `/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF2'` is the start of a here-document. You are feeding the `expect` interpreter the text that you've stored in your bash script (I assume, since you tagged it `bash`). The first line should be `#!/usr/bin/expect` and then there should not be a line with `EOF2`. If you need variables that you have in some other script (presumably a `bash` script), pass those as arguments to your `expect` script.

Comment: Yes I am using multiple  variables from the bash script. This is bottom section of the script. I had basically scripts that were doing different tasks and I have integrated bash and expect script into one.

Comment: "_I have integrated bash and expect script into one_" - when it's a _not so trivial_ piece of code written in another language, I suggest that you let it be a separate script. It makes it a lot easier to maintain and the interface to the `expect` script becomes clearer. Pass `$ip` etc. as arguments to the `expect` script to get access to what you need.

Comment: You need to learn the [tag:tcl] language before using Expect. Tcl's `split` manual: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.html . Try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you are more comfortable with shell scripts.

Comment: I have tried to do **for { set index 0 } { $index < [llength $tarts] } { incr index 2 }**  but doesn;t work.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The title is "increment loop by 2", but the question asks about "incrementing the (tart/ip) variable". Are you looking for `set nextIp [lindex $ips $index+1]` or `set biggerTart [expr {$tart + 1}]`?

Comment: I want to be able to spawn two ips in parallel. Right now I am able to do only one.

Comment: @glennjackman can you guide how can I spawn two IPs at a time in parallel?

Comment: is it possible to spawn two Ips at a time?

Comment: It is possible to spawn multiple things. You just need to keep track of the various `spawn_id`s. However, you're not asking this question clearly. Step back, forget about the current implementation, and tell us what data you have and how you need to use it. Don't even think about expect and spawn, talk to us about your requirements. And do it in the question, not in comments.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/677049/377345) on U&L SE.

Comment: Asad, referring to somewhere else (a deleted question), let me explain that if you have a question and find an answer yourself, then it is appreciated if you turn that into a Q/A pair with a well asked question (according to [ask]) and a helpful answer (according to [answer]). Just make sure that the question actually contains all info needed by OTHERS to also answer the question (you might have to do that first to get the question reopened). If you do that there you can be sure of my upvote as soon as I notice.